# Nginx and PHP: no write permissions

Tags: php, nginx, file-permissions

I have a problem with a PHP application (Baikal) that runs on Ngnix. The application has no (longer) write permissions for one of its config files. The problem might have occured after upgrading PHP.

Here is some information about my setup:

- Operating system: Arch Linux
- Nginx version: 1.16.1
- Nginx user: http
- PHP version: 7.4.1
- Application: Baikal 0.4.6
- Nginx config:

```
    server {
       listen              443 ssl http2;
       listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
       server_name         –––––––––;
       root                /usr/share/webapps/baikal/html;
       index               index.php;
       include             include/ssl.conf;
       include             include/letsencrypt.conf;

       rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /dav.php redirect;
       rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /dav.php redirect;
       charset utf-8;

       location ~ /(\.ht|Core|Specific) {
          deny all;
          return 404;
       }

       location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
          try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
          include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
          fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
       }
    }
```

The application reports that the file *Specific/config.php* is not writable. Full path is */usr/share/webapps/baikal/Specific/config.php*.
I have set the permissions of the file to 777 for testing purposes; without success. I tested the PHP function `is_writable`. It returns `false` for that file. `fopen` says that the filesystem is read-only (it is not).

I have read a lot about SELinux preventing write operations, but as I said, I use Arch Linux which is no SELinux.
I think it has something to do with the fact that PHP is not allowed to write outside the root directory set in Nginx, but I can't get it fixed.

Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what about removing `Specific` folder from `location {deny all}` block?

Comment: As far as I understand the configured locations are for routing external access, not internal. I tested that anyway, but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, nailed it. Pew.

As of PHP 7.4 PHP-FPM protects the system by mounting `/usr`, `/boot`, and `/etc` directories read-only.

This [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/996397/failed-to-open-stream-read-only-file-system-when-trying-to-create-file-outsid/997496) and this [issue](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/2756) led me to solution to just move the application folder outsite of `/usr`.